# configurationerrorsexception: data at the root level is invalid not thrown on debug

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am having some trouble with a .net windows forms application trying to connect to a sql server 2008 sp2 db on a windows 2003 server. I have tried running it on Windows 7 and xp. same problem.

On calling the code

```
m_objConn = new SqlConnection();
```

I get the ConfigurationErrorsException. The exception then shows a path to my config file in ()brackets  ---->System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position1.

The file is not xml, there is no code presuming it is xml that I can find and the line posted above that it crashes on is not referencing any objects relating to that config file. Also, this is a recent problem the application has worked for years. The only thing we changed is the machine that the sql server runs on.

The big kicker is that this only happens outside of the debugger so it is very difficult to figure out. I have read that apps running in the debugger will connect to network computers differently then apps not debugged. Could be related...

Is there something hidden in the background with files named *.config that I don't know about? Anyone with any insight?

Comment: The App.config/Web.config family of files should be XML of a specific format. If yours isn't XML, that's the cause of your exception.

Comment: thank you @JoachimIsaksson. That was it. I changed the file extension to .info and it worked. I'm still curious, I didn't mention this before but we are on Visual Studio 2010, while I think the original was developed on 2005. I wonder if in VS 2005 this was not a problem.